# Getting data from Parse as “Optional(test)” and want to do something with that “test” part

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am new to Parse and I am trying to retrieve my first password (my password is: test). But I can only receive it as “Optional(test)”. The “test” there is actually the password that I want to receive but I can’t get it out of the paranthesis. My code is as follows;

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var userNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var credentialsLabel: UILabel!


@IBAction func checkCredentialsButton(sender: AnyObject) {





    var query = PFQuery(className:"userName")

    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("the id of my object") {

        (userNameRetrieved: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil && userNameRetrieved != nil {

            println(userNameRetrieved)
            println("Username has been retrieved succesfully")
            println(userNameRetrieved?.objectForKey("username"))

            } else {

            println(error)

        }
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.userNameTextField.delegate = self
    self.passwordTextField.delegate = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(userText: UITextField) -> Bool {
    userNameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}


}
```

And my logs are as follows;

```
Optional(<userName: "my username", objectId: “the id that i am using", localId: (null)> {
ACL = "<PFACL: “my acl">";
username = test;
})
Username has been retrieved succesfully
Optional(test)
```

Is there a way for me to use that password to log my user in?

Also, is there a way for me to retrieve an array of passwords that are registered to check if the password is true or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use if let to unwrap the optional

```
    @IBAction func checkCredentialsButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var query = PFQuery(className:"userName")

    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("the id of my object") {

        (userNameRetrieved: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil && userNameRetrieved != nil {
          if error == nil && userNameRetrieved != nil {
          if let userArray = userNameRetrieved {
           print(userArray)
           if let username = userNameRetrieved?.objectForKey("username") {
             print(username)
           } 
        }  
       } else {
         println(error)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: YES! Oh my god thank you so much! Is there a way for me to get a whole array of passwords though?

Comment: same way you can retrieve the array using the same if let syntax, please up vote the answer. Thanks